# How to represent friend relation when friend is also an user

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a database with these two requisites:

- A user could have friends.
- A friend is an application's user.

In my conceptual design, I have represent it this way:

[image]

I have a couple of questions:
1. **Is that correct?**
2. **Is Friend an entity? Do I have to add a table `Friend`?**

I think I will need a table Friend with two columns, both Foreign keys to User table.

Comment: I think the design is correct. But in friend table you should keep only the Ids and friendship related data. means user_id1 and user_id2 where both user_id1 and user_id2 are users. Both are friend to each other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scheme that you are trying to set up looks very much like a self-referencing many-to-many scheme:

[image: Many-to-many self-referencing entity.]

There is no separate `Friend` entity, only a "friendship link" table called `UserFriend`. It has two attributes - the `ID` for the user entity representing a friend, and the `ID` of the user whose friend it is. "Friendship" may also contain additional attributes, such as the date when friendship has been established, the context in which the friendship exists (college, work, family) and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll do it this way. Now, I'm thinking about the SQL statement to look for all my friends on UserFriend table: `SELECT * FROM UserFriend WHERE userId = myId OR friendId = myId;`. And also, I'm thinking how to avoid do this: `INSERT INTO UserFriend VALUES (1, 2);`. And some time later: `INSERT INTO UserFriend VALUES (2, 1);`. What do you think?

Comment: I am wondering about cardinality on this diagram. Shoudn't it be 2 relation one-to-many from User to UserFriend? First relation is saying that user has many friends, and second that user is a friend of many users.

Comment: @kpater87 You're right, I switched `1` and `*` on the bottom line! Thanks!

Comment: @VansFannel Maybe you can do both insert on the begining or treat it like e.g. in Facebook: User 1 is saying: "User 2 is my friend" and you do `INSERT INTO UserFriend VALUES (1, 2);` but it need confirmation, so when User 2 confirm relationship you will make second insert: `INSERT INTO UserFriend VALUES (2, 1);`

Comment: @VansFannel In SQL to retrieve all friends of a user `@MyUser` you do `SELECT u.* FROM UserFriend uf JOIN User u on u.Id=uf.FriendId WHERE uf.UserId=@MyUser`. Unfortunately, avoiding circular dependencies, direct or indirect, is up to your application.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If I'm user_1, and I set that my friend is user_2. Another user, user_3 set that I, user_1, I am his friend. Now my friends are: user_2 and user_3. But your previous SQL doesn't retrieve that user_2 and user_3 as my friends Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel This is sorrect - in this scheme, friendships are directional. You can keep the directionality in place (i.e. someone "friending" me does not make him my friend, unless I also "friend" him), or change the query to retrieve the inverse of the relationship: `SELECT u.* FROM UserFriend fo JOIN User u on u.Id=fo.UserId WHERE fo.FriendId=@MyUser`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I prefer to change the query. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Maybe I'm wrong, but your diagram doesn't represent that an user can have 1 or more friends. Am I wrong?

Comment: @VansFannel Correct - that's the omission that [kpater87 noted in his comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807584/how-to-represent-friend-relation-when-friend-is-also-an-user/17808043?noredirect=1#comment25984351_17808043). The asterisk and `1` are switched on the `FriendId` arch. I don't have the original drawing (I did it online and saved as PNG) so I cannot correct it easily.